# DT:: Datatable is displayed twice in a shiny application

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I have a `shiny` application in which a `dataTable` is displayed when the user selects `Sector` A from the `radioButtons` menu in the sidebar. The problem is that it is displayed twice. I checked it in browser mode too. Why does this happen I display the whole app here since it may be caused by the `if` logic of the app. `renderTable()` works fine so I guess there is an issue with `DT`

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)  
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=shinytheme("slate") ,
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("rad")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tabers"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server = function(input, output) {

  output$rad<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("radio", label = "",
                 choices = list("Home"=1,"About" = 2, "Sector A" = 3, "Sector B" = 4,"Sector C" = 5), 
                 selected = 1)
                 #selected = character(0))
  })

  output$tabers<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$radio)) {
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabF",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Global"),
        tabPanel("Performance")
      )
    }
    else if(input$radio==3){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents",
                 output$table <- renderDataTable({
                   mtcars
                 })
                 ),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      )
    }
    else if(input$radio==4){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabD",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"

                 ),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      ) 
    }
    else if(input$radio==5){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabE",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"

                 ),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      ) 
    }
    else if(input$radio==2){

    }
    # Left last else in here but should not get called as is
    else if(input$radio==1){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Global"),
        tabPanel("Performance" )
      ) 
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `renderTable` does the same thing. For some reason, the output of `renderDataTable({mtcars})` gets displayed twice, first through `uiOutput`, second through `dataTableOutput()` (both are in `mainPanel`). Commenting the line `dataTableOutput("table")` fixes the behavior in that it shows the table only once. Interestingly, removing the assignment like so:

```
else if(input$radio==3){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents",
                 renderDataTable({
                   mtcars
                 })
        ),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      )
    }
```

also renders the table once. So it looks like when inside `renderUI`, `renderDataTable` just creates the output without requiring a `dataTableOutput` in the UI.

This seems to allow (for better or worse) to easily render different tables in different tabs without corresponding output entries in the UI.

```
else if(input$radio==3){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents",
                 renderDataTable({
                   mtcars
                 })
        ),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      )
    }
    else if(input$radio==4){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabD",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents",
                 renderDataTable({
                   iris
                 })
        ),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      ) 
    }
```